# Линии через весь макет, как сверстать?

Tags: html, css

Если присмотреться к макету на нем видно линии (я их пометил красными линиями для наглядности) которые проходять через весь сайт с самого верху и вниз, подскажите как их сверстать что бы они совпадали на всех секциях сайта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты хоть пыталсья ?

Comment: Вообще без понятия как это сверстать :(

Comment: и ты хочешь чтобы тут тебе дали готовую верстку?

Comment: я не целый макет прошу мене сверстать, а подсказать как сделать эти линии что через целый сайт идут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #e0e1e5;
}

.container-line {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.container-line::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}

.container-line::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я почти уверен, что это вам дизайнер сетку для удобства оставил, но раз уж хотите и ее заверстать, то держите резиновый вариант:

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}
.container.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,
      grey,
      grey 1px,
      transparent 1px,
      transparent 25%);
}

.container.main:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container main">

</div>
```